# Custom field after address in WooCommerce admin edit order pages

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In the WooCommerce admin edit order pages, there are billing and shipping addresses in the following format:

- name surname
- address
- postal code
- city
- country

What hook can I use to put a custom field value after address and before postal code value?

I'm expecting this result with custom field value between address and postal code:

- name surname
- address
- custom field value
- postal code
- city
- country